# wordpress get_children doesn't reflect edits to image galleries

Tags: wordpress

I have a very simple theme that retrieves all image gallery links for each post using the get_children() function. 
Unfortunately, there's some strange bugs - first, if images are not uploaded when creating the post and are instead selected from the media library, they don't show up after publishing. Also, if I do any edit after a post has been created, be it reordering the images, adding new ones, deleting images, even deleting the whole gallery and creating a new one, they don't show up either. Refreshing browser cache doesn't do a thing.

If i change to one of the base themes, the images show up, and the right links are there when querying the db directly.

I reproduced the basic problematic code in a one file micro-theme, but the issue still happens:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php echo $post->id; 
$args = array(
                  'numberposts'     => -1,
                  'order_by'        => 'menu_order',
                  'order'           => 'ASC',
                  'post_mime_type'  => 'image',
                  'post_parent'     => $post->ID,
                  'post_status'     => inherit,
                  'post_type'       => 'attachment'
                );
$images = get_children($args); 
if ( empty($images)){
echo "nothing";
}
foreach ( $images as $id => $image ) :
echo $image->post_title;
endforeach;
?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm stumped, I've tried using different functions to retrieve the posts with the same result, deactivated all plugins, nothing.
I'm testing both on OSX mavericks and an Ubuntu vps, could it be some database cache thing i'm supposed to flush somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `'post_parent' => $post->ID,` you will only get attachments to that page. That's part of the reason not all of the images show up.

But the bigger problem is that galleries are handled differently than posts/pages/attachments. Galleries only exist in the shortcode- they're not stored in the db- so you can't query them with `get_posts` or `get_children`.

To customize the way galleries are rendered you'll have to either hook into the wordpress code that creates the gallery, or deregister that function and write your own.

[**This question**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4343/how-to-customise-the-output-of-the-wp-image-gallery-shortcode-from-a-plugin) answers how to manipulate shortcode if you were writing a plug-in- but the process will be the same from a theme.

:-)